# What is the difference between systemd's user and system services?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to understand a little better systemd by writing some services.

I have difficulties in understanding the differences between those 2 services for instance, well I'd like to be sure I understand them correctly would be more appropriate.

So for instance I got rtorrent service, defined as rt as a system service, that I can enable for user X,Y,Z, with sudo systemctl enable rt@userX.service

```
➜  ~  cat /etc/systemd/system/rt@.service
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
Requires=network.target local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
User=%I
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s rt -n rtorrent -d rtorrent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t rt:rtorrent C-q
WorkingDirectory=/home/%I/
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I got dropbox defined that way :

```
➜  ~  cat /etc/systemd/user/dropbox@.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh %h/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I understand well, the dropbox service can be started / stopped / enabled / disabled at a user level, for many users, even if that user isn't an admin. Does it mean I can as userX enable it for userY ?
As for the rt service, only an admin can enable / start / stop it ...
Is that the only difference between a system service and a user one ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're a bit muddled, yes.  ☺  You have:

- A set of *system* services that are managed by the *system-wide instance* of systemd; which are each an instatiation of a *template service unit* in the file `/etc/systemd/system/rt@.service`.
- A set of *user* services that are managed by the *per-user instances* of systemd; which are each an instantiation of a *template service unit* in the file `/etc/systemd/user/dropbox@.service`.

You now need to understand this:

- There is one system-wide instance of systemd.  It always runs.  It's process #1.  Only an administrator has the authority to control system services.
- There are multiple per-user instances of systemd.  They are started/stopped on demand as users logon/logoff.  They are not process #1.  There is a maximum of one per user, however many times the user is logged on.  Only that user (or an administrator) has the authority to control xyr own services.

A *template* service unit is a way of making multiple ad-hoc service units on the fly, that differ in the template parameter.  The actual instantiated service units are named as a combination of the template name and the parameter.

Combined, this all means:

- In your `rt@.service` the parameter is a user name, used to specify the user that the service runs as and the working directory that it runs in.  So you can instantiate services such as `rt@euri10.service` and `rt@david.service`.  These are *system* services, managed by the *system-wide* instance of systemd, and it takes an administrator to start and stop them.  It *just so happens* that there's one per user.
- In your `dropbox@.service` the parameter is ignored.  You can instantiate services such as `dropbox@wibble.service` and `dropbox@phooey.service`.  These are *user* services, managed by the *per-user* instances of systemd.  Each user has xyr own separate set of template instantiations which that user can start and stop.

You possibly didn't want your dropbox service unit to be a template.  Or you're now figuring out what that `Environment=DISPLAY=%i` setting was all about.  ☺